# curl fails to take self signed certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssl, curl

I've installed apache 2 server with self signed certificate.My browser is showing 'It works!' when I tried to connect to the sever. But from an application when I issued cur_easy_perform() the call failed with error code 60: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates!

Does the browser really verified the server's certificate? If I want to avoid the above error what need to be done further?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this coz of the certificate is n't been added to certificate bundle? if it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl uses the SSL certs maintained by your OS (normally in /etc/ssl/certs, or /user/lib/ssl/crts) to verify certs. Your browser will normally use its own certificate store. Hence adding a cert to your browser won't necessarily allow curl to verify it.

To add the cert to the store used by curl, download the cert to /etc/ssl/certs (or whatever directory your distribution keeps its ssl certs in), and run c_rehash in that directory.

Comment: I've one more question..... how to tell apache web server to verify client SSL certificate?

Comment: This is answered in this question : http://serverfault.com/questions/291466/apache-client-certificate-authentication